# Send URL as name

Tags: php

actuly i have a problem in my url page, i want to send the user provided url in the url in place of pre-defined url page like(user-profile.php). i have to replace **user-profile.php** to the user provided name like(ram.php), plshelp me out of this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question and add some code examples? We ca't help you unless you provide some code and attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to use .htaccess file and mod_rewrite. This let's you use different URLs than the actual file names from the server. In this way you write the URLs in the links the way you want to see them and in the .htaccess file you write the translation to the real file name.

Comment: A proper answer should contain examples for how to solve the issue, not just high level suggestions.

Comment: oh i forgot about .htaccess file but thank you for the help me out of this satution